# Executing /usr/bin/R on remote machine via SSH does not work

Tags: r, bash, ssh

I want to login to a remote server via ssh and start R afterwards.

```
ssh -X user@166.167.0.1 '/usr/bin/R'
```

> Fatal error: you must specify '--save', '--no-save' or '--vanilla'

Which tells me that start of R failed.
How can I solve it ?

Comment: I'm suspecting you could solve it by specifying `'--save', '--no-save' or '--vanilla'`

Answer (score 1):

According to this Q&A in [this github](https://github.com/clbustos/Rserve-Ruby-client/issues/19)

It seems like the source of the problem is not with `/usr/bin/R` parameters, but with the parameters of the `RServe` itself.

> This is a message from `Rserve` itself, and in the documentation. eg:
>   You can start `Rserve` with `Rserve(args="--no-save")`
>
> Check here under Launching Rserve in the link below
>   https://www.rforge.net/Rserve/doc.html

**More info from** [Rserve docs](https://www.rforge.net/Rserve/doc.html):

> **Launching Rserve**  Rserve comes now as an R package, so one way to start Rserve is from within R, just type
>
> ```
> library(Rserve)
> Rserve()
> ```
>
> That command knows how to find Rserve, how to setup the environment
>   and how to start it, regardless of your platform.
>
> Note: depending on how you are running R, it may require additional
>   parameters such as --no-save (R will tell you). In that case you have
>   to pass that parameter in the args argument such as
>
> ```
> Rserve(args="--no-save")
> ```
>
> However, Rserve is a stand-alone program, so it can be started
>   directly as well. If you installed Rserve from a source package (on
>   unix), type:
>
> ```
> R CMD Rserve
> ```
>
> Depending on the purpose and libraries on your computer you may want
>   to add --gui-none or --no-save (see R documentation). Rserve passes
>   any parameters to the underlying R engine except for Rserver-related
>   parameters (see command line arguments). After initialization Rserve
>   daemonizes itself to work as a server. It can be shut down gracefully
>   (i.e. it will wait until all existing connections are finished) if it
>   recieves shutdown command from an authorized connection. It terminates
>   not so gracefully if it receives usual termination signals.
>
> If no config file is supplied, Rserve accepts no remote connections,
>   requires no authentication and file transfer is enabled. For more
>   details about how to configure Rserve, see below.

---

Answering the question in the note:

You should configure `Rserve` on the remote host.
The configuration process can be done once, using `Rserve` configuration files.

In order to login to the remote host, you can use the following command:

```
ssh -X user@166.167.0.1
```

Start `Rserve`  with `--no-save` parameter:

```
R CMD Rserve(args="--no-save")
```

[Here](https://github.com/s-u/Rserve/issues/56) is a discussion how to setup `Rserve` as a service.

Comment: @peterpisher did I answer your question?

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer. Its informative to know how Rserve works but my question is still to start Rserve with ssh  and configure the environment properly

Comment: @PeterPisher - updated my answer with more info. Does it works for you now?